# Unable to encode list in pub/sub message

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-api-python-client

I am trying to publish a pub/sub message from a cloud function in python3.7. The message is a list object which I am trying to encode and publish to the pub/sub topic.

The code is as follows:

```
projects_list=[['test-main', 'my-project']] #this is the list which I am passing

for projects in projects_list:
      topic_name = 'projects/{project_id}/topics/{topic}'.format(
      project_id=os.getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT'),
      topic='topictest'  
      )
      projectsjson=json.dumps(projects) #I am converting the list to json object
      
      message = {
        "data": base64.b64encode(projectsjson), #this line throws type error
        "attributes": {
        "batch_start_time": batch_start_time,
                    }
        }
```

Error:

```
**TypeError**: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

If I directly pass the list object

```
 message = {
        "data": base64.b64encode(projects), #this line throws type error
        "attributes": {
        "batch_start_time": batch_start_time,
                    }
        }
```

I am getting this error:

```
**TypeError**: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'
```

### Update

As per the answer below I made the following changes to the code:

```
 message = {
        "data": base64.b64encode(bytes(projectsjson,encoding='utf8')),
        "attributes": {
        "batch_start_time": batch_start_time,
                    }
        }
```

The encoding takes place, however when I call the publish method below:

```
response = service.projects().topics().publish(
            topic=topic_name, body=body
        ).execute()
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code changes have worked for me:

```
message = {
        "data": base64.b64encode(bytes(projectsjson,encoding="utf8")).decode(),
        "attributes": {
        "batch_start_time": batch_start_time,
                    }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `b64encode()` requires a `bytes-like` object and returns the encoded bytes.

The function `dumps()` serializes an object and returns a string.

Therefore, you must convert the output of `dumps()` to bytes.

Change this line:

```
"data": base64.b64encode(projectsjson)
```

To this:

```
"data": base64.b64encode(bytes(projectsjson))
```

Comment: Thanks you, i have updated my comments above regarding the code change

Comment: @user1403505 Which version of Python?

Comment: python3.7 is the version i use